# Why are the answers to my question removed and the question protected?

Tags: support

I have an open question (with a bounty) on which some suggestions for answers were given. Now the question is suddenly protected but the existing answers removed. ATM there is no way for me to accept one of the given answers and to reward the bounty.

Is this an error or am I missing something?

The question:
[How to use GPS without using Google Location Services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89622/how-to-use-gps-without-using-google-location-services)

Comment: Two were deleted by myself, which had basically no relation to the question at all. The account that posted them has a somewhat...unusual post history that also factored into this significantly. The third was flagged, apparently, though handled by another mod. I'll need to defer that explanation to him for the time being, at least (he should be notified of this question, though). The protection was a system-imposed one that kicks in after 3 answers get deleted, but it seems excessive here so I'm lifting that.

Comment: Ok. I have only seen 2 answers (from two different accounts)  of which one answer was indeed completely off. The other however was more or less what I asked for, I just needed a bit of time to test it a bit better.

Comment: For what it's worth, the other answer I removed was posted by the same account as the one you've described as "completely off", and was equally irrelevant to your question. I think it was probably deleted before you had a chance to log in and see the notification, which was then removed from your inbox. The account appeared to be trying to win some bounties but (without going into too many specifics) was not "playing fair". So just to allay any possible concerns: those two weren't deleted simply for being wrong (that's what we have voting for, after all).

Comment: I may add the only half-way useful answer was deleted after bein flagged for its low quality by multiple users. See [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for details on that.

Comment: The other answer was flagged and didn't look to be of very high quality when I was reviewing the mod queue (and came from a 1 rep user). On this second review (and with your input) it does seem to be an answer to the question. I'll undelete it, but if someone could improve the quality of it, that'd be great.

Comment: Yes, the answer is a bit low on description, I'll ask the user to add some relevant data.
If he does not respond to this I could do it myself but adding to the answer is normally not allowed/appropriate within Stackexchange I believe?

Comment: I think that depends. If it'd give the answer a completely different meaning, it shouldn't be done. But if you e.g. include details from "behind a link" of a "link-only answer" which is "orphaned" by its original poster, that's fine. Between the two, there's a kind of "gray area" of course. To me, your approach sounds good: Ask the answerer to improve, and if there's no response, do it yourself (while making clear which part is yours – e.g. introducing it with "Edit by Requist:").

Comment: Could someone post an official answer instead of using comment to answer? Because... well, it's an answer to this meta question (also, to prevent unanswered question bump by Community user)